# Haskell PINNED or STACK memory for performance

Tags: performance, haskell, ghc

I'm trying to benefit from an optimisation that sometimes occurs in GHC (8.4.3), where a "build" of a large volume of data is put in PINNED memory. (I may not have all the terminology correct here). Here's a simple example:

*Pinned1.hs:*

```
main = print $ sum $ tail ([1..100000000] :: [Int])
```

then:

```
ghc -O2 Pinned1.hs -prof -rtsopts
Pinned1 +RTS -hc -p -xt
hp2ps -e8in -c Pinned1.hp
```

shows ~40K PINNED and virtually no STACK usage, and `Pinned1 +RTS -hd -p -xt` shows the ~40K is ARR_WORDS.

The Pinned1.prof shows:

```
total time  =        2.14 secs   (2137 ticks @ 1000 us, 1 processor)
total alloc = 8,000,046,088 bytes  (excludes profiling overheads)
```

Having looked at the -sdump-simpl, I can see the kind of code that leads to this. Here's a slightly more complex example, back-translated from Core into Haskell code, where the same thing happens:

*Pinned2.hs:*

```
main = print $ sum $ snd $ wgoC 1 0
wgoC :: Int -> Int -> (Int, [Int])
wgoC n finalState =
  let (nxt, ys') = case n of 100000000 -> (finalState, [])
                             _         -> wgoC (n+1) finalState
  in (n, n + nxt * 9: ys')
```

wgoC passes the next n back, which is used in the calculation of the values in the list. It reports ~40K PINNED/ARR_WORDS memory, and almost no STACK, and this profile output:

```
total time  =        5.50 secs   (5500 ticks @ 1000 us, 1 processor)
total alloc = 16,800,046,112 bytes  (excludes profiling overheads)
```

However, this:

*Pinned3.hs:*

```
main = print $ sum $ snd $ wgoD 1 0
wgoD :: Int -> Int -> (Int, [Int])
wgoD n finalState =
  let (ttl', ys') = case n of 100000000 -> (finalState, [])
                              _         -> wgoD (n+1) finalState
  in (ttl' + n, n + (ttl' + n) * 9 : ys')
```

doesn't complete after 2 mins. It does complete with a value of only 1000000, and I see no PINNED memory and STACK usage (~100M) instead. (I think it is the STACK usage that is making it run much more slowly, somehow).

The main difference I see between Pinned2 and Pinned3 is that Pinned3 includes information from the recursive call in the returned state (the fst of the returned pair: the cumulative sum of subsequent values), but Pinned2 only includes the parameter to wgoC.

So my questions are:

Q1) Where (in the [compiler pipeline](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/wikis/commentary/compiler/hsc-main)) does the decision to use PINNED memory happen? -ddump-simpl shows no obvious difference, nor -ddump-cmm (though it's a little complicated so maybe I'm missing something).

Q2) What is the PINNED/STACK decision based on? (The only references I can find to PINNED, such as [this](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/wikis/commentary/rts/storage/gc/pinned), say it's useful for FFI calls, but it seems it's also been adopted for this "optimisation" as well).

Q3) Is there some way to modify Pinned3 so that it does use PINNED?

Q4) (as a last resort) Is there some other tweak to Pinned3 so that there is enough STACK space, and it runs in a reasonable time? (Naïvely, I would expect similar performance to Pinned2).

[Note that I'm only trying to understand the PINNED/STACK mechanism here. I'm sure there are other ways to write Pinned3 so it fuses nicely and needs hardly any memory, but this question is not about that.]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pinned memory doesn't play a role here.

This program:

```
main = print $ sum $ tail ([1..100000000] :: [Int])
```

does not use **any** pinned memory *directly*.  The pinned memory you're seeing is from the initialization of the runtime system itself.  Pinned memory is allocated by GHC's byte array primitives; in user code, you're most likely to see pinned memory usage when using `Data.Text` or `Data.ByteString` both of which use byte arrays for their internal implementation. For this program, I'm going to guess that the I/O buffers for stdin and stdout are pinned, but maybe it's something else.  Anyway, lists of `Int`s won't pin anything.

Like (almost) all Haskell programs, `Pinned1.hs` uses tons of heap and tons of stack (gigabytes of each) but, critically, frees it as quickly as it allocates it (or if you prefer when talking about the stack, "pops" it as quickly as it "pushes" it).  The same is true of `Pinned2.hs`.  These programs are functioning correctly.

The problem with `Pinned3.hs` is not that it uses stack instead of pinned memory, but rather that it uses even more stack than `Pinned1` and `Pinned2` and fails to pop it as quickly as it pushes it, so stack accumulates.

So, why does `Pinned3` accumulate stack?

Generally speaking, stack accumulates in a recursive call if some part of the result of the recursive call is the target of a function application when it returns **AND** evaluating that part of the result itself requires another recursive call.  Consider the program:

```
eatStack 100000000 = 1
eatStack n = 1 + eatStack (n + 1)
main = print $ eatStack 1
```

which, compiled and run with:

```
stack ghc -- -O2 -prof -rtsopts EatStack.hs
./EatStack +RTS -hd -p -xt
stack exec hp2ps -- -e8in -c EatStack.hp
```

produces the usual sort of pyramid-shaped stack accumulation (with a peak of 1.4G or so).  The problem here is that the return value of the recursive `eatStack (n+1)` call is subject to the function application `\x -> 1 + x` when it returns, and calculating that result itself requires further recursion.  That is, calculating `eatStack 0` requires pushing `\x -> 1 + x` onto the stack before calling `eatStack 1` which can only return its result after pushing `\x -> 1 + x` onto the stack before calling `eatStack 2`, and so on.  The result is stack accumulation.

Notably, constructor applications are handled differently.  The following program:

```
noStack 100000000 = []
noStack n = 1 : noStack (n + 1)
main = print $ last (noStack 1)
```

which applies the partially applied constructor `(:) 1` to the recursive result `noStack (n+1)` uses no stack.  (It appears to use 40k of pinned, but again that's really the runtime system.  `EatStack` uses 40k of pinned, too.)  In some cases (not here), constructor application like this can cause heap accumulation, but it doesn't generally accumulate stack.

For your `Pinned2` and `Pinned3` examples, something similar is going on, though it's obviously a little more complicated.  Let's look at `Pinned2` first, and consider evaluating `wgoC 1 0`.  Matching the case and substituting in the arguments, the evaluation is equivalent to:

```
wgoC 1 0 = 
  let (nxt, ys') = wgoC 2 0
  in (1, 1 + nxt * 9 : ys')
```

When `sum . snd` demands the first element of the list, namely the thunk `1 + nxt * 9`, this forces `nxt` to be evaluated via the recursive call.  Because this return value is subject to a function application (namely `\x -> 1 + x * 9`), this uses a bit of stack, but the evaluation of the recursive call:

```
wgoC 2 0 = 
  let (nxt, ys') = wgoC 3 0
  in (2, 2 + nxt * 9 : ys')
```

immediately yields the required value for the locally bound `nxt` in the `wgoC 1 0` call, namely the first element of the returned tuple `fst (wgoC 2 0) = 2`, without requiring further recursion.  So, we take that value 2, pop off the continuation `\x -> 1 + x * 9` and pass the value to the continuation to yield `1 + 2 * 9 = 19`.  That gives the list's first element, with no net stack usage. The rest of the list, namely the locally bound `ys'` in the `wgoC 1 0` call, is still in a thunk `2 + nxt * 9 : ys'` as closed by the `wgoC 2 0` call.

When the next element is demanded, we'll need some stack to apply the continuation `\x -> 2 + x * 9` to the result `nxt` in the recursive `(nxt, ys') = wgoC 3 0`, but this will be evaluated the same way, immediately returning `nxt = 3` and a thunk for `ys'`, so the continuation `\x -> 2 + x * 9` will be popped off the stack and applied to `nxt = 3` without further recursion, yielding `2 + 3 * 9 = 29` and a thunk `3 + nxt * 9 : ys'` as closed by the `wgoC 3 0` call.

Each element can be forced with no net stack use.  We push a continuation and then immediately pop it and apply it to a part of the return value from the recursive call that doesn't *itself* require further recursion.  The result is no net stack accumulation.

Now, consider `Pinned3`, and the call `wgoD 1 0`:

```
wgoD 1 0 =
  let (ttl', ys') = wgoD 2 0
  in (ttl' + 1, 1 + (ttl' + 1) * 9 : ys')
```

When `sum . snd` demands the first element of the list, namely the thunk `1 + (ttl' + 1) * 9`, this forces `ttl'` to be evaluated via the recursive call.  Because there's a pending function application `\x -> 1 + (ttl' + 1) * 9`, this will use a bit of stack.  The recursive call:

```
wgoD 2 0 =
  let (ttl', ys') = wgoD 3 0
  in (ttl' + 2, 2 + (ttl' + 2) * 9 : ys')
```

can only provide the required value for the locally bound `ttl'` in the `wgoC 1 0` call by evaluating the first component of the return tuple `ttl' + 2`, but this requires forcing `ttl'` via the recursive `wgoD 3 0` call.  Because `ttl'` is subject to a function application `\x -> x + 2` when it returns, we push a little more stack and proceed to evaluate:

```
wgoD 3 0 =
  let (ttl', ys') = wgoD 4 0
  in (ttl' + 3, 3 + (ttl' + 3) * 9 : ys')
```

To get the required `ttl'` as locally bound in the `wgoD 2 0` call, we need to evaluate the first component of return tuple from `wgoD 3 0`, namely `ttl' + 3`.  This is a function application `\x -> x + 3` which we push on the stack, applied to `ttl'` returned from the recursive call `wgoD 4 0`.

So, `Pinned3` pushes a sequence of continuations `\x -> x + 2`, `\x -> x + 3`, `\x -> x + 4`', etc. onto the stack, all in an effort to evaluate the first component of the tuple returned by `wgoD 2 0`, never getting an opportunity to pop anything until it gets to `wgoD 100000000 0`, and then it finally gets a number `finalState = 0` as the first tuple component, if there's enough stack to get that far.  Then all that stack will be popped off as the continuations are applied, and we'll have the first element of the list!

Once it gets through that, things aren't so bad.  All of the expressions `ttl' + n` have been evaluated at this point, and they can be reused in calculating the expressions `n + (ttl' + n) * 9`, so the remaining elements can be generated relatively quickly, though -- since their values must be kept somewhere -- you'll also get accumulating heap usage at roughly the same rate as stack usage.

You can swap out the 100000000 for something like 10000000 (seven zeros), and that runs in a reasonable amount of time and shows accumulation of both stack and heap in a pyramid shape; it peaks at 1.4 gigs or so before dropping back down to zero.

I don't see any really straightforward way of "fixing" this while still keeping the algorithmic structure of `Pinned3` intact.

Comment: Thank you for your very helpful and complete explanation.

Comment: I see the PINNED thing was a red herring. As you say, Pinned3 also has it, but it's not shown ordinarily. I presume -hd by itself only shows the "main culprits", which is fair enough. However, you can see it using `Pinned3 +RTS -hd -hdARR_WORDS -p -xt -i0.001`, which shows the same ~40K. And it makes sense that this is some kind of system/IO overhead or something.

Comment: Another thing that had led me astray: Pinned1 shows `total alloc = 8,000,046,088 bytes`. I should have taken more notice of the "note that the total memory allocation figure isn’t the same as the amount of live memory needed by the program at any one time" [here](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.4.3/docs/html/users_guide/profiling.html#cost-centres-and-cost-centre-stacks). It makes much more sense that it is allocated in small chunks that are then discarded almost straight away.